# Please reopen YaCy service question not solved by generic answer

Tags: support, reopen-request

I created [How can I stop YaCy from starting when my machine starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482320/how-can-i-stop-yacy-from-starting-when-my-machine-starts) and was pointed to [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services) as a general answer. Unfortunately I voted to close my own question before confirming that the answer did indeed work (it didn't), and it has since been confirmed as a duplicate.

I have updated my original question to reference the general answer, and note how it doesn't apply to this specific service (YaCy search engine). Please reopen the question to allow this non-general case to be addressed. Thanks!

(If I discover a generalisable solution, I will happily update the general answer and vote to close again :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done...

You have correctly done the right thing - editing your question with details of what you have tried and what has not worked.

As an alternative in the future - you could use a custom flag and one of the site mods will look at your explanation and reopen if required.

Comment: thanks for the tip re flags!